# Closed Graph implies closed Kernel?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces and $T:X\to Y$ a linear operator. We have that closed graph implies closed kernel?

I mean, take $x\in Cl(\ker T)$ then exists a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset \ker T$ ; $x_n\to x$. We want to show that $x\in \ker T$.
Because of $x_n\in \ker T$ for each $n$, we know that $(x_n,0)=(x_n,T(x_n))\in Graph(T)$, and it converges to $(x,0)$ as $x_n\to x$. Well, but as $(x_n,0)$ is a convergent sequence in the graph of $T$ which is closed, then $(x,0)$ is also in the graph of $T$ , thus $T(x)=0$ and $x\in\ker T$, hence $\ker T$ is closed.

Moreover, if $T:X\to \mathbb{K}$ is a linear functional with closed graph in a normed vector space, then $T$ is bounded. And that is a consequence of the statement which says that any linear functional with closed kernel is bounded.

OBS: We are not using banach space here, so the Closed graph theorem does not apply.

Is that right? Any notes, correction and sugestions would be very welcome.

Comment: There is a simpler argument. $\ker T=P({\rm Graph}T \cap (X\times \{0\}))$ where $P(x,y)=x.$

Comment: Hey @Bazyli, the image of a closed subspace under a bounded operator need not be closed!

Comment: That's true. But in this case the subspace has a special form $\ker T\times\{0\}$ and $P$ is the projection on the first coordinate.